# I am receiving an error in swift from the Protobuf/Wrappers import in the Pod file

Tags: ios, swift, podfile

in my GFBProtocolBuffers.h, I am receiving this error at this line.

```
#import <Protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
```

It says lexical or preprocessor Issue, 'Protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h' file not found. I am not sure what is even going on here. If anyone has any clue on how to help me that would be appreciated, also if you know what is going on and could teach me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem . I used all the methods mentioned on the internet but still doesn't work. Then I realized that all the header files not found was from cocoapods, so I re-installed the cocoapods using pod install, and thus solved the problem.